# Large file won't allow checkin, claims to be checked out to the current user

Tags: document-library, versioning, check-out

A out of the box library with versioning on and checkout required.  The files that show the issue are Word and PowerPoint.  All of these files are larger than our average files and run about 5 to 10MB

1. User checks out the file and makes edits.
2. User tries to check the file in, office reports the file is already check out, but documents are checked out to the user in question

This happens sporadically, and while we have a work around it does not make my users feel confident in SharePoint.  Most times, maybe most of the time, it works correctly, but it does fail.

What should I be looking for to fix the problem?

Comment: is it happening only on the library, it could be work flow or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was eventually identified as a lack of bandwidth between the servers and the offices in the field.